# Нужна помощь с Stream java

Tags: java, потоки-данных

Создать программу, в которой выводятся все положительные целые числа, сумма цифр которых равна заданному значению. Использовать потоки данных.

Comment: Вы не прочитали правила сайта. Здесь не выполняют ваши домашние задания за вас. Здесь могут помочь решить проблему, если вы пытаетесь что-то сделать, но у вас не получается. Для этого вам нужно показать, что вы пытаетесь сделать, и рассказать, что именно не получается. Читайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 6):

Ответ: это невозможно, так как таких чисел бесконечное множество.

Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: то есть ЦЕЛЫХ ПОЛОЖИТЕЛЬНЫХ чисел, сумма которых равна, допустим, 3, бесконечное множество? Интересно

Comment: @notaProgrammer 111, 1110, 11100, ...

Comment: @notaProgrammer Для вас это новость? Интересно